# Multiple Root Nodes in Cytoscape

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am creating a tree with Breadthfirst layout in Cytoscape.

In layout options, I have set a node as root. But is there a way that I can have 2 nodes as root nodes?
I see in cytoscape reference has layout options in following way:

```
var options = {
  name: 'breadthfirst',
  roots: undefined, // the roots of the trees
};
```

Now, individual nodes can be set as root nodes by using its ID. For 
example:

```
roots: "#a"
```

How can I do this So I have multiple roots for a single tree as represented in this image?

[Multiple Root Tree representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8AMa.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I found out that the easiest way to do it was to use a comma separator. 
The code will look something like this -

```
roots: "#a,#b"
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved that putting a extra class called 'level3' in that nodes and I wrote the next line:

`cy.layout({name: 'breadthfirst', directed:false, roots:'node[classes @*="level3"]',padding: 5});`

remmember that you can add some different classes to nodes just using a blank space between them

Comment: Why not use the class selector (e.g. `.lvl3`) with built-in classes rather than storing a data field named `classes`?